# sed replace multiple spaces

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am using this command:

```bash
echo $s | sed 's/ /%20/g'
```

This works totally perfect if the folders are in format like:

`Untitled Folder Testing`

But if folder name has more spaces in it like:

`Untitled    Folder   Testing`

The code won't work. How can I make sed replace each space it finds with value `%20` like the code above?

Comment: Your 2 examples are identical. Can you explain what is working and what isn't?

Comment: notice the spaces count between the folder title, if you have more than one space between the name of folder title it wont work

Comment: `sed` _does_ convert each space it receives, but `echo $s` changes all whitespace sequences (including multiple spaces, or tabs) in $s each to a single space. If you want to preserve whitespaces _in `echo`_, use `echo "$s"`. Alternatively in bash use a herestring: `sed 's/ /%20/g' <<<$s`

Comment: The extra spaces are not noticeable in HTML. I've edited the question to show what you mean.

Comment: Since you're using `bash`, you don't need `sed` at all: `echo "${s// /%20}"`

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you have access to tr)

```
echo "${s}" | tr -s " "
```